# Tratamentos de erro 404 e 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, ddd

Boa tarde, a minha dúvida é a seguinte como ainda sou iniciante em asp.net e sobre o DDD ainda eu tenho uma certa dúvida que é em qual camada usando o padrão DDD eu implementaria o tratamento de erro 404 e 500, se seria na camada de presentation ou na infra mesmo ou qualquer outra camada e porque seria implementada nessa camada.

Answer (score 0):

Crie dentro de
**Apresentation/Views/Erro/** 
Crie dois arquivos 
**Erro404.cshtml

Erro500.cshtml**

Adicione ao seu web.config a seguinte linha

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.html" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Erro404" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Erro500" />
</customErrors>
```